# HTML5 JavaScript POST file upload

Tags: javascript, html, upload, xmlhttprequest

Recently I've been looking into adding a simple HTML5 drag and drop to my already simple php file upload script.
I have read lots of tutorials and other solutions but I can't seem to understand the whole sending the file to server part.
From what I understand, XMLHttpRequest will send the data, but it will do it without reloading the page. This, I do not want. Currently the script I'm using will take the POST data and produce the file upload output, eg. server download link, thumbnail if image etc.

How can I have the drag and drop submit the POST data and either access the upload output or reload the page?

Edit:
I'm using the following for the drag and drop:

```
    <div id="drop_zone">Drag and drop a file here</div>

    <script>
          function handleFileSelect(evt) {
            evt.stopPropagation();
            evt.preventDefault();

            var files = evt.dataTransfer.files; // FileList object.


            uploadFile(files[0]); //<-- This is where most examples will use XMLHttpRequest to construct form and send data
          }

        function handleDragOver(evt) {
            evt.stopPropagation();
            evt.preventDefault();
            document.getElementById('drop_zone').style.backgroundColor = "#faffa3";
            evt.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy'; // Explicitly show this is a copy.
        }
        function handleDragLeave(evt) {
            document.getElementById('drop_zone').style.backgroundColor = "";
        }

          // Setup the dnd listeners.
          var dropZone = document.getElementById('drop_zone');
          dropZone.addEventListener('dragover', handleDragOver, false);
          dropZone.addEventListener('drop', handleFileSelect, false);
          dropZone.addEventListener('dragleave', handleDragLeave, false);                 
    </script>
```

Comment: If you want to reload the page, there's no reason at all to use XMLHttpRequest; just do a regular form POST.

Comment: @Pointy How can I set the file input field after a file has been dropped?

Comment: If you would post more information on exactly what sort of "drag and drop" mechanism you're investigating, you might get more help. File input fields can be native drop targets in some browsers.

Comment: ... however, that said, I'm not sure exactly what has to happen in order to make an `<input type=file>` field work in an ordinary form as a drop target.

Comment: @PeeHaa I have added the drag and drop code I am using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more reading and searching around I've come to the conclusion that what I originally wanted cannot be done.

The solution I am going with is to simply have a large transparent/hidden `<input type="file">` covering the drop zone. The dropped filename will be read from the input with javascript and displayed in the drop zone. This of course will rely on the browser to support the drag and drop files into html file inputs.
From there my upload script will pretty much operate as if the user had used the visible file selector.

Apologies for not being too clear on what I wanted. I wasn't so sure myself. And thanks for the replies/comments.

Answer (score 0):

If you use JQuery or some other event-capable javascript library you should be able to catch the drag event and submit your form.

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/API/1.8/Draggable

http://api.jquery.com/on/

But no XMLHttpRequest involved...

Comment: How can I set the file input field after a file has been dropped? I thought that isn't possible due to the security risks.